# How to undo iptables-save?

Tags: linux, firewall, iptables

On a standard Ubuntu server have I done

`vi /etc/sysctl.conf` did I enable

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

then executed

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -p /etc/sysctl.conf
```

and then

```
iptables-save
```

but what I wanted to do was

```
iptables-save > /etc/iptables.up.rules
```

**Question**
I assume `iptables-save` have overridden the default iptables rules, which was not what I wanted.

How do I undo that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`iptables-save` just outputs your iptables rules into a savable format. If you didn't redirect the output into a file nothing should have changed.